# MSE of randomized decision in Normal distribution

Tags: sufficient-statistics, mse, decision-theory, risk

Suppose a sample $\bf{X}$$=(X_1,...,X_n)$ is from $X\sim N(\theta,1)$. The sample mean $T(\bf{X}$$)=\bar{X}$ is sufficient to the population mean $\theta$.

For $\delta(\bf{X}$$)=X_1$, the decision $\delta_T(\bf{X}$$)$ such that $(\delta_T(\bf{X}$)$|\bar{X}=t)\sim N(t,(n-1)/n)$ has $E[\delta_T(\bf{X})$$]=E[X_1]=\theta$ and $Var[\delta_T(\bf{X})$$]=1=Var[X_1]$. I was able to verify these.

One thing that I want to check further is the risk function of these decision rules which is usually called the MSE. The formula is $R(P_{\theta},\delta_1)=E_\theta[(\delta({X})-\theta)^2]$. Their MSE should be equal based on sufficiency and decision theory, but I don't know how to construct this.

**Definition:** Given a statistic $T(X$) sufficient for $\theta$, for any decision procedure $\delta(X)$ one can always find a randomized decision rule $\delta_T(X)=\delta(T(X))$, which depends only on $T(X)$ and does
as well as $\delta(X)$ in the sense of having the same risk function, i.e., $R(\theta,\delta) = R(\theta,\delta_T)$, for all $\theta\in\Theta$.
Hence, the decision can be made based directly on the sufficient statistics $T(X)$ instead.

**Progress:** Based on MSE definition, I get:
$$E[(X_1-\theta)^2]=var(X_1)+[E(X_1-\theta)]^2=1$$
$$E[(\bar{X}-\theta)^2]=var(\bar{X})+[E(\bar{X}-\theta)]^2=\frac{1}{n}$$
These two should be equal since the risk functions should be the same. Where am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: The notations are confusing: do you mean $R(\theta,\delta_1)=\mathbb E_\theta[(\delta_1(X)-\theta)^2]$ so that the risk applies to any decision $\delta_1(\cdot)$? And also what is the distinction between $\delta(x)=x_1$ and $\delta_T(x)$?

Comment: @Xi'an Yes. I also added a definition on how the decision rules relate.